Override input to package in nixpkgs
With this flake:
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = {
    self,
    nixpkgs,
    flake-utils,
    ...
  }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem
    (
      system: let
        pkgs = import nixpkgs {
          inherit system;
          overlays = [
            (final: prev: {
              duckdb = prev.duckdb.overrideDerivation(old: {
                cmakeFlags = old.cmakeFlags ++ ["-DSKIP_EXTENSIONS=jemalloc"];
              });
            })
          ];
        };
        python = pkgs.python311;
        buildInputs = with pkgs; [
          (python.withPackages (ps:
            with ps; [
              duckdb
            ]))
          duckdb

        ];
      in
        with pkgs; {
          devShells.default = mkShell {
            inherit buildInputs;
          };
        }
    );
}

I can successfully build duckdb without jemalloc, but the python package (python3Packages.duckdb) is still using the version of duckdb from before the overlay. To test:
echo "SELECT installed FROM duckdb_extensions() WHERE extension_name='jemalloc';" | duckdb

Returns false, whereas:
import duckdb
assert not duckdb.connect().execute("SELECT installed FROM duckdb_extensions() WHERE extension_name='jemalloc';").fetchone()[0]

Fails.
Clearly, I don't know how to override the input to python3Packages.duckdb. I thought that setting an overlay would propagate across the whole of pkgs (in the let bind) so that pkgs.python311.duckdb would end up being passed the overlayed duckdb.
How ought I to go about this? And what have I got wrong about overlays?

Does nix show-derivation confirm that the cmakeFlags update didn't happen?

@CharlesDuffy yes (nice pointer btw, thanks). There are two derivations for duckdb in the output, and {HASH}-python3.3.11.9-env.drv depends on the wrong one. why there are two derivations I don't know.

for reference as it took me a while to figure out, nix derivation show .#devShells.x86_64-linux.default --recursive inspects the devshell, I'd not thought of that!

Aside: Personally, I'd avoid with. More explicit (in the sense of "easier for language servers / typecheckers / human readers to unambiguously interpret the corner cases") to explicitly refer to ps.duckdb. Also, the distinction between pkgs.duckdb (which your overlay covers) and ps.duckdb (which is... subject to more context-sensitive evaluation) is relevant, and using with obscures it.

Anyhow, I'd start by looking at how the duckdb Python package is defined in nixpkgs, and whether it's in fact referring to pkgs.duckdb in its dependencies, or getting the dependency some other way / via some other name.

In point of fact this is working.
My answer to @CharlesDuffy in the comments was wrong (I'm not sure how...): the derivation is in fact being overriden, so you can indeed override like this: the overlay is applied (conceptually) before the derivation gets nixpkgs.duckdb.
On the other hand, all the pythonPackages.duckdb derivation requests is the src (and a few other metadata attributes) from nixpkgs.duckdb. (This is why cmakeFlags doesn't show up in the output.) The actual build happens completely differently, via a setup.py, with minimal overridability. (Patching the file is possible, but for some reason even setting use_jemalloc to false with a bit of hackery isn't enough to get a build without jemalloc.) Thus I still can't build without jemalloc, but at least it's clear what's going on with nix.
